# Django Channels permissions

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

Is there any supported way in Django Channels framework to write custom permission to connect to specific consumers?

something like DRF:

```
class MyConsumer(generics.APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, MyCustomPermission]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution, I've come up with this solution:

1. Create a `Permissions` class with a `check_permissions` method.

```
    from channels.exceptions import DenyConnection

    class Permissions(object):
        permission_classes = []
    
        def check_permissions(self):
            try:
                for permission in self.permission_classes:
                    if permission(scope=self.scope).validate() != None:
                        raise DenyConnection
            except PermissionError:
                raise DenyConnection
```

2. Create a `BasePermission` class.

```
class BasePermission(object):
    def __init__(self, scope, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.scope = scope

    def has_permission(self, *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
        return True

    def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not self.has_permission(*args, **kwargs):
                return PermissionError
        except Exception:
            return RuntimeError
        return None
```

3. Then override `has_perm` with your custom permission.

```
class NotAnonymousUser(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
        try:
            return not isinstance(self.scope["user"],AnonymousUser)
        except Exception:
            return False
```

4. Finally inherit the `Permissions` class and call the `check_permissions` method.

```
class MyConsumer(Permissions, JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    permission_classes = [NotAnonymousUser]

    def connect(self):
        self.check_permissions()
                   .
                   .
```